# HTML column row breaking after padding left

Tags: html, css, html-table, text-alignment

I have a section which looks like this:
[image]

The fields `Budget` and `Status` should be more on the right side, but I don't know how to achieve this without breaking it. The issue doesn't appear in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/om6jd4pn/

I tried putting the text to the right using `padding-left:20em;` in CSS and this HTML, but it's breaking after the first letter.
[image]

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <span class="bsprojectGroupTitle" id="indentBudget">Budget</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9" id="projectBudget">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <span id="indentStatus">Status </span>
        </div>
            <div id="bsprojectProjectPhaseLine">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Would it suffice to do "text-align: right" on those cells?

Comment: @niorad No because it barely increases the gap between the columns

Comment: then you'll have to increase the cell before (to add the white-space there), and shrink this cell from 4 to 3.

Comment: @niorad Sorry I'm fairly new to this. Can you tell me which values I have to change?

Comment: ok so all of your cols need to add up to 12. "col-md-3 + col-md-3 + col-md-3 + col-md-3" and so on. so if you want to shrink the last one, you need to enlarge another one, like "col-md-3 + col-md-3 + col-md-4 + col-md-2"

Comment: @niorad Thanks, that worked. But if that field has a value, it will go onto the next line and not stay in the same one. How can I avoid that? (Like the column with the dates)